# Wordpress always load same page - index.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website with a custom theme. Everything works fine on index.php but when I create one more page (index2.php or adminpage.php) and try to load that in-browser WordPress will redirect me to index.php

OK, this is file setup: https://ibb.co/9n7Qdxt . This is URL of normal index.php: https://ibb.co/M69f5bD . And this is a problem: https://ibb.co/kJFW4ZZ
ps: adminpage.php is empty but browser load index.php
image: https://ibb.co/x2T82dc

```php
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="Mon, 22 Jul 2002 11:12:01 GMT">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
    <title></title>

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Franklin:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
```

PRoblem: Wordpress always redirects the user to index.php regardless which url user enter ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've described you haven't added the adminpage.php as a template file and assigned it to a page in the backend. Here's a link to help you with template theming in WordPress.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: Thanks, Template Hierarchy that's what I didn't understand.